# How to use Itext7 in powershell V5, Exception when loading pdfWriter

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, itext7

Before i created a powershell script with iText7, I created with the new iText7 class a C# application. This works without a problem.

Now I converted it into poweshell script and get a error.

with iTextsharp everything works well, but Itextsharp is EOL so iText7 is the recommended way.

Whats wrong with my code?

```
[string] $pdfDocuFilename = "C:\pdfTestProject1\Exports\export_" + (Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + ".pdf"

Add-Type -Path "C:\pdfTestProject1\dlls\BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\pdfTestProject1\dlls\itext.kernel.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\pdfTestProject1\dlls\itext.layout.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\pdfTestProject1\dlls\itext.io.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\pdfTestProject1\dlls\NLog.dll"


$pdfWriter = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter]::new($pdfDocuFilename)
$pdf = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument]::new($pdfWriter)
```

### The exception is:

Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot open document."
At C:\pdfTestProject1\printPDF.ps1:26 char:1
+ $pdf = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument]::new($pdfWriter)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PdfException

### My wanted result:

The only thing a person wantes is a working code :-)

thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain your use case briefly? I am truly interested in why you would do that when you can e.g. create a command line app using native tools of .NET stack doing the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a couple of dependencies are missing. iText7 depends on `Common.Logging` version 3.4.1 (can be downloaded [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Common.Logging/3.4.1)), which on turn depends on `Common.Logging.Core`, same version 3.4.1 (can be downloaded [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Common.Logging.Core/)).
Also make sure the BouncyCastle dependency is `Portable.BouncyCastle` version 1.8.1.3 (can be downloaded [here](http://Portable.BouncyCastle)).

You don't need the `NLog` dependency, at least it's not needed for iText 7 to work.

That being said, here is the code snipped that worked fine in my set up (iText 7.1.6, PowerShell 5.1):

```
[string] $pdfDocuFilename = "C:\temp\" + (Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + ".pdf"

Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\Common.Logging.Core.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\Common.Logging.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\itext.io.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\itext.kernel.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll"


$pdfWriter = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter]::new($pdfDocuFilename)
$pdf = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument]::new($pdfWriter)
$pdf.AddNewPage()
$pdf.Close()
```

Comment: Thank you! After adding the Common dll´s everything worked!