# Print pdf files on different printers depending on their content

Tags: powershell, pdf, printing, itext, extract

I want to print .pdf-files on different printers - depending on their content.
How can I check whether a specific single word is present in a file?
To queue through a folder's content I've build the following so far:

```
Unblock-File -Path S:\test\itextsharp.dll
Add-Type -Path S:\test\itextsharp.dll
$files = Get-ChildItem S:\test\*.pdf
$adobe='C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe'
foreach ($file in $files) {
  $reader = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor]
  $Extract = $reader::GetTextFromPage($File.FullName,1)
  if ($Extract -Contains 'Lieferschein') {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Lieferschein"
    $printername='XX1'
    $drivername='XX1'
    $portname='192.168.X.41'
  } else {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Etikett"
    $printername='XX2'
    $drivername='XX2'
    $portname='192.168.X.42'
  }
  $arglist = '/S /T "' + $file.FullName + '" "' + $printername + '" "' + $drivername + " " + $portname
  start-process $adobe -argumentlist $arglist -wait
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
  Remove-Item $file.FullName
}
```

And for now I got 2 problems with it:

**1st**: `Add-Type -Path itextsharp.dll` gives me an error.

```
Add-Type: One or more types in the assembly cannot be loaded. Get the LoaderExceptions property for more information. In line: 2 character: 1
```

I've read that it might be due to the file being blocked. There is no information about that in the properties though. And the `Unblock-File` comand and the start doesn't change/solve anything.

After using `$error[0].exception.loaderexceptions[0]` I get the information that `BouncyCastle.Crypto, Version=1.8.6.0` is missing. **Unfortunatelly I can't find any sources for that yet.**

**2nd**: Will `if ($Extract -Contains 'Lieferschein')` work as I intend? Will it check for the phrase after the `Add-Type` gets loaded successfully?

**Alternatively**: There's also the possibility to make it depend from the content's format. One type of the files has the size of DIN A4 for example. The other one is smaller than that. If there's an easier way to check for that, you'd make me happy aswell.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the error? Is `itextsharp.dll` a .Net assembly?

Comment: I've added the newly gained information into the question.

Comment: FYI, as per the owners of [iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/), it is no longer supported.  As per the link ---   iTextSharp is EOL, and has been replaced by iText 7. Only security fixes will be added --- We HIGHLY recommend customers use iText 7 for new projects, and to consider moving existing projects from iTextSharp to iText 7 to benefit from the many improvements

Comment: Know that iTextSharp is a Q&A here on SO fairly regular. See from the SO search box above ---https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=powershell+itextsharp

Comment: I mean, really, why fight so hard with something that can easily be done in Python. Search for `pypdf2` library.

Comment: A paid solution may have better support for layout analysis, text ordering and Unicode normalization and font handling, particularly for tricky languages (Thai, Japanese, Arabic, etc.). I'm not familiar with pypdf2, so it's possibly it ticks all the boxes. Anyway, all of the above is fairly important when attempting to search text in PDFs. Finding text in PDFs is one of those things that feels like it should be so simple, but it turns out, it can be a lifetimes work, hence the commercial offerings :)

Comment: That said, I'm aware if this is a simple internal tool, you may not need a commercial offering. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st**:

After finding the correct version (1.8.6) on [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.BouncyCastle/1.8.6) the `Add-Type` commands  work perfectly. As expected I didn't even need the `unblock` command as it was not marked as a blocked file in the properties. Now the script starts with:

```
Add-Type -Path 'c:\BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'c:\itextsharp.dll'
```

**2nd**

Regarding the check-queue: I just had to replace `-contains` with `-match` in my `if` clause.

```
if ($Extract -Contains 'Lieferschein')
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching for a keyword in a pdf using Powershell and iTextSharp.dll. It's a very common thing. You then just use your conditional logic to send to whatever printer you choose.
SO, something like this should do.

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\path_to_dll\itextsharp.dll'

$pdfs     = Get-ChildItem 'C:\path_to_pdfs' -Filter '*.pdf'
$export   = 'D:\Temp\PdfExport.csv'
$results  = @()
$keywords = @('Keyword1')

foreach ($pdf in $pdfs)
{
    "processing - $($pdf.FullName)"
    $reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader -ArgumentList $pdf.FullName

    for ($page = 1; $page -le $reader.NumberOfPages; $page++)
    {
        $pageText = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor]::GetTextFromPage($reader, $page).Split([char]0x000A)

        foreach ($keyword in $keywords)
        {
            if ($pageText -match $keyword)
            {
                $response = @{
                    keyword = $keyword
                    file    = $pdf.FullName
                    page    = $page
                }
                $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $response
            }
        }
    }

    $reader.Close()
}

"`ndone"

$results | 
Export-Csv $export -NoTypeInformation
```

***Update***

As per your comment, regarding your error.

Again, iTextSharp is a legacy, and you really need to move to iText7.

Nonetheless, that is not a PowerShell code issue. It is an iTextSharp.dll missing dependency. Even with iText7, you need to ensure you have all the dependencies on your machine and properly loaded.

***As noted in this SO Q&A:***

[How to use Itext7 in powershell V5, Exception when loading pdfWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55915290/how-to-use-itext7-in-powershell-v5-exception-when-loading-pdfwriter)

Comment: Thanks for that. I can edit it for my purposes. But what about the fact that there's an error upon loading itextsharp.dll as I have written in the question?